# Git: convert repository to use --reference

Tags: git

I have several local clones of a repository, each weighing in at about 11GB. I use multiple workspaces in order to work on different branches simultaneously. I recently discovered the 'git clone --reference' feature, which allows multiple clones to share objects with a reference, saving space.

How can I convert my existing workspaces to use --reference? The reason is that I want to keep my stashes and local topic branches as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the path to the alternate object store in

```
$REPO/.git/objects/info/alternates
```

Note that this is not the path to the repo but the path to the repo objects.

so to link to /users/andrewc/myrepo I would use

```
echo "/users/andrewc/myrepo/.git/objects" > NEW_REPO/.git/objects/info/alternates
```

Based on testing by the OP it appears that `git repack` can cause some of the objects to be copied over again.  `git gc` can be used to reclaim object speace.

There is confusing commentary on the git devel list [here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Bringing-a-bit-more-sanity-to-GIT-DIR-objects-info-alternates-td7564428.html)

Comment: Thanks for your idea, however it seems insufficient: before: $OLD_REPO is 11G, after adding alternates, gc, and repack becomes 8.1G. Brand new clone --reference is 2.6G.


On the other hand, doing just a gc and repack on another repo (without adding alternates) brings it only to 10G, so maybe there is some deduplication going on after all?

Each workspace has about a dozen specific topic branches, and I can't imagine how keeping the objects specific to these branches would use up nearly 6G of space.

Comment: just "git repack", I see -l would've been good. Also, it may be that build artifacts (which I used to think went in some other dir) are the source of the bloat. Will update when build's complete.

Comment: I would say you should only be comparing of the `.git` directory here to eliminate anything else from the equation.

Comment: Ah, right. So a standalone workspace has a .git of 1.3G, a natively --reference workspace is 17M, and a converted workspace is 144M. That's good enough, so I guess it worked :)

Comment: Whoa, "git repack -adf" is actually a bad idea, as it blew the converted workspace up to 1.3G, negating any benefits. In fact, from what I've read "git repack -a" is what's recommended when wanting to convert a --reference workspace into a standalone one. I can't seem to revert back to smaller with git repack, unfortunately.

Comment: Without the -d you will end up with objects in duplicate pack files.  The link I cited seems to waffle between having -f and not.

Comment: Ater more testing with git 2.1.1, it seems "git repack" variants do nothing useful sizewize, except "git repack -a" which will bring all objects locally to make the repository autonomous again. You can use "git gc" to then return to a dependent repository. Could you amend your answer with this so I can mark it answered?

Comment: Furthermore, as documented in gitrepository-layout, the alternates file can contain a relative path, but that path is relative to the objects/ dir, not info/. So for example if you have /path/to/repo-ref and /path/to/repo-dep, you want to echo "../../../repo-ref/.git/objects" > /path/to/repo-dep/.git/objects/info/alternates, or, if repo-ref is a bare repo, "../../../repo-ref.git/objects". I figure this is useful to spell out if anyone's searching for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63194/discussion-between-john-de-largentaye-and-andrew-c).